# How to write SVG manually so it is displayed in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I'm trying to write some SVG for illustration and while it renders well in:

- Chrome
- Firefox
- http://svg.enshrined.co.uk/ 
  see screenshot below for an idea

**But** nothing gets displayed in:

- Inkscape (Inkscape 0.92.5 (2060ec1f9f, 2020-04-08)).
- [wmflabs](https://tools.wmflabs.org/svgcheck/index.php) (though it did not report any issues)

Minimal working example to reproduce is below and was validated against:

- W3C
- http://svg.enshrined.co.uk/
- [wmflabs](https://tools.wmflabs.org/svgcheck/index.php)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        <!-- last joint -->
           <defs>
           <g id="disk">
            <!-- define here the joint -->
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="100"/>
            </g>
         </defs>
      <use href="#disk" />
</svg>
```

Google / Firefox rendering:
[image]:

While Inkscape shows only a blank sheet.

I'm assuming some specifics to Inkscape (I've seen special handling for layers, but would rather avoid reverse engineering if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        <!-- last joint -->
           <defs>
           <g id="disk">
            <!-- define here the joint -->
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="100"/>
            </g>
         </defs>
      <use xlink:href="#disk" />
</svg>
```

Basically all I did here was to use `xlink:href=` instead of `href=` and declare the namespace prefix `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`. I tested this and it works in Inkscape, Firefox and Google Chrome.

I don't know why `href` doesn't seem to work in Inkscape. To get an answer to that, perhaps better to ask the Inkscape developers.

Comment: awesome, thanks ! just checked and it works. and as to why it is needed i'll dig in the inkscape documentation now that there is a vector for where to start from.